# I want to pass a jquery variable to a PHP page, sometimes i am getting the varible and sometimes not

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP page named logo_design_3.php. 
I have used Jquery to post the variable "grand_total" to another page named logo_design_3_sql.php. But unfortunately sometimes i'm getting that variable on the next page and sometimes not. 
Any idea where i'm doing wrong?

Here is the snippet of logo_design_3.php page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function load1() {
    document.getElementById('hide2').style.display = 'none';
    return false;
}

function toggle() {
    document.getElementById('hide1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('hide2').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('hidrad').checked = 'true';
    document.getElementById('silver').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('bronze').checked = false;
    document.getElementById('gold').checked = false;
}

function load2() {
    document.getElementById('hide1').style.display = '';
    document.getElementById('hide2').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var grand_total = 0;

    $("input").live("change keyup", function() {

        $("#Totalcost").val(function() {

            var total = 0;
            $("input:checked").each(function() {

                total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
            });
               var textVal = parseInt($("#min").val(), 10) || 0;

               grand_total = total + textVal;

               return grand_total;
        });

     });
         $("#next").live('click', function() {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'logo_design_3_sql.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                grand_total: grand_total
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // do something;

            }
        });

    });

});
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    var num = document.getElementById("min").value;
    var num = parseInt(num, 10);

    if (num < 299) {
        document.getElementById("min").value = "299";
        alert("Minimum Amount Should be 299");
    }
}
```

```
</head>
<body onLoad="load1()">
<div id="wrap">
<div class="main-container internal">
<div class="main wrapper clearfix section">
<article>
<section>
                     <h1>Step 3. Contest details</h1>

                     <h2>Create a contest that attracts the right designers to your brief.</h2>

                    <p>We've got the largest design community online so it's important to create a contest that attracts the kinds of designers you want to work on your brief.</p>
                    <div id="form">
                        <form method="post" id="logoform3" action="logo_design_3_sql.php">
                            <label>What design package do you want?</label>
                            <br>All packages come with a 100% money-back guarantee and you own full copyright to the final design.
                            <br>
                            <p></p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="b" onClick="load2()" value="299" id="bronze">
                                <label>Bronze - $299</label>
                                <br>Get lots of great designs at a great price
                                <br>
                                <li style="list-style:circle">Expect around 30 designs</li>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="b" onClick="load2()" value="499" id="silver">
                                <label>Silver - $499</label>
                                <label class="block badge">Most popular</label>
                                <br>Attract great designers and get priority support
                                <br>
                                <li style="list-style:circle">Your project will be shown to designers before bronze projects</li>
                                <li style="list-style:circle">Expect around 60 designs</li>
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <input type="radio" class="radio" name="b" onClick="load2()" value="799" id="gold" checked="true">
                                <label>Gold - $799</label>
                                <label class="block badge">Work only with our top designers</label>
                                <br>Work only with our most talented designers and receive 1-on-1 support
                                <br>
                                <li style="list-style:circle">Only our best designers can participate to ensure top quality</li>
                                <li style="list-style:circle">A dedicated account manager will guide you to the best result possible</li>
                                <li style="list-style:circle">Expect around 60 designs of the highest quality</li>
                            </p> <a onclick="toggle(); event.preventDefault();" href="#" style="text-decoration:none;border-bottom:1px dotted blue;" id="hide1">I want to create a custom package</a>

                            <br>
                            <div id="hide2">
                                <p>
                                    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="bbb" id="hidrad" checked="true" id="name_ur_price" value="0">Name your price:
                                    <input type="number" width="10px" style="background:#ccc; border:1px solid #ccc !important;" id="min" min="299" name="min" onChange="validate();" id="name_your_price" name="name_your_price">.00($299 minimum)
                                    <br>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <label>Contest preferences</label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="" value="39.00" align="middle" id="private_contest" name="private_contest">
                            <label>Make your contest private (+$39.00)</label>
                            <br>Your contest will be hidden from search engines and the general public. Only members of the Square Designs community can see your contest and they must agree to a Non-Disclosure Agreement (NDA) to see the details. We provide a standard template for the NDA or <a href="" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').click(); return false"> you can upload your own(as a PDF).</a>

                            <br>
                            <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" style="visibility: hidden; width: 1px; height: 1px" multiple />
                            <label id="design_dura" style="left:!important">How quickly do you need your design?</label>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="c" value="0">
                            <label>Standard 7 days (FREE)</label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="c" value="39" id="days_3">
                            <label>In 3 days(+$39.00)</label>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="c" value="59" id="days_2">
                            <label>In 2 days(+$59.00)</label>
                            <br>
                            <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="c" value="79" id="days_1">In 24 hours(+$79.00)</label>
                             <h2>TOTAL :</h2>

                            <p>
                                <input type="text" name="Totalcost" id="Totalcost" style="background:#f5f5f5; border:none; outline:none; box-shadow:none; font-size:18px;" disabled/>
                                <br>
                            </p>
                            <input type="submit" class="sumit-styled" value="Next" style="margin-left:-15px;" id="next" name="next">
                            <input type="submit" class="sumit-styled" value="Save Now" style="margin-left:-15px;" id="save" name="save">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <aside>
                    <img src="img/slide2_2.png" webstripperwas="img/slide2_2.png" alt="mockup" />
                    <p><em>Donec sed odio dui. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.</em>

                    </p>
                </aside>
            </article>
            <!-- END MAIN -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is from logo_design_3_sql.php page:

```
<?php include ( "config.php"); 
$total=$_POST[ 'grand_total'];
 $sql="INSERT INTO form2 (total)VALUES('$total')" ; 
if($total>0)
{ $res = mysql_query($sql); } 
if($res) 
{ echo "<script> window.location.replace('logo_design_4.php')</script>"; }
 else { echo "<script> window.location.replace('logo_design_3.php')</script>"; }
 ?>
```

I have issue regarding -> window.location.replace('logo_design_4.php') too. Even if $total is properly inserted in the table, the page that get navigated after insertion is "logo_design_3.php". Why so?

Comment: Do you mean it's not posting to the other page, or it's posting the wrong value?

Comment: well in my case its posting
1. correct value
2. Nothing
3. Zero

Comment: Have you tried putting `console.log("Posting " + grand_total)` in the function, to see if it's being called and what it thinks the value is?

Comment: @Barmar I have used an alert Right after this: $.ajax({
                url: 'logo_design_3_sql.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {grand_total: grand_total},
                success: function(data) {}
            });
And i'm getting the right value always only problem is i'm not getting the correct value on next page.

Comment: What do you mean by "next page"? AJAX doesn't change the page.

Comment: by next page i meant logo_design_3_sql.php

url: 'logo_design_3_sql.php'

Comment: How are you determining what it's sending to the next page? Have you looked in the Network tab of Developer Tools, to see what value it thinks it's sending to the page?

Comment: Is there another piece of code in your page that performs a reload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try live function as below

```
$("#next").live('click',function () {
    $.ajax({
            url: 'logo_design_3_sql.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {grand_total: grand_total},
            success: function(data) {}
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: `.live` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, removed in 1.9. Use `.on`.

Comment: If it works sometimes, then it's not delegation that is the issue.  If it were, it would never work.

Comment: Only necessary if "next" was generated dynamically

Comment: @andrew, i didn't get you.
what's only necessary if next was generated dynamically?

Comment: @sanki .live() or as Burmar states .on is only required if "next" was created with js after the page was loaded

Comment: @sanki - can you paste your full code here? I mean HTML,jquery and PHP code

Comment: @vishalshah: DOne, please check.

Comment: @sanki : use used $total=$ _POST[ 'grand_total']; where it should be no space in $_POST like $total=$_POST[ 'grand_total'];

Comment: @sanki:Also change input type of next button from submit to button

Comment: @vishalshah: the post error is just here, mistakenly done while posting the question, in my code that's as it should be.
&
I need that button to be of type submit. And how does that affect the purpose?

Comment: @sanki:everytime form gets submitted and reset when you submit..I used button type and it works fine

Comment: If you want to use submit as button type then you can simply $_POST['Totalcost'] in sql.php file and remove jquery of next button call as it is not required

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare the grand_total variable on the global scope.

```
var grand_total = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {



$("input").live("change keyup", function () {

    $("#Totalcost").val(function () {

        var total = 0;
        $("input:checked").each(function () {

            total += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        });
        var textVal = parseInt($("#min").val(), 10) || 0;

        grand_total = total + textVal;

        return grand_total;
    });

});
$("#next").click(function () {

    $.ajax({
                url: 'logo_design_3_sql.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {grand_total: grand_total},
                success: function(data) {}
            });
        });
    });
```

and please don't use your PHP Code on a production system. You have to check your POST Variables (http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: It doesn't have to be declared globally. It just need to be in a scope that includes both handler functions, and the document.ready function body is such a scope.